# What datatype to use for daytime (hour, minute) in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, sqldatatypes

I have to store a daytime (HH24:MI) in a column in Oracle. So only the hour and minute parts of a DATE. Which data type should I use?

`DATE` / `TIMESTAMP` store both too much information, that can distract, I think.

`NUMBER(4,2)` (as 18,3) is my preferred choice, or `VARCHAR2(4)` (like "1830").

Or is it a better way to make two columns, one for hour and one for minute?

Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: what about `INTERVAL` ?

Comment: You should still consider to use `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` date type. At the end it makes your life easier, most probably.